# What criteria should we use for QCing for ALL "identification-request" questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, identification-questions, guidelines

We've previously voted that we need a set of guidelines to quality control (QC) [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions that will be added to our [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help). These guidelines will be applied to ALL (new and old) [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question since the tag's inception.

So I ask the community, how should we go about making these guidelines?

Please format and present your list of guidelines for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) in the form you wish for it to appear in the help center.

The guidelines should include, but are not limited to the following:

- List of criteria to follow
- Examples of things that fit the criteria (i.e. are certain criteria more welcomed, like images, audio, and/or video?)
- Minimum number of criteria that must be present in the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question
- Any what to do for certain exceptions (e.g., What if the criteria are fulfilled but the details are too vague?)
- What action should be taken for questions that fail this criteria?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Please note that as of May 8, 2016, **ALL** [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions are now [**off-topic**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions/2806#2806).
>
> However, such question are still welcome [in our main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) for users with with at least [20 rep](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (globally on StackExchange).

---

> ### The following is outdated and exists solely for archival purposes

**Hey you!** You're probably here, because you asked an [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question that was "put on hold" or "closed." 
If you would care to know why, please take sometime to read [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/a-new-users-guide-to-our-site-and-whats-wrong-with-their-identification-reque/2491#2491).

In short, **these guidelines are here to help us help you find what you're looking for**. We realize you can't remember everything, but every bit of detail you can remember (no matter how insignificant it may seem) can be a lot of help. All we ask for you to fulfill, at minimum, three (3) of these guidelines.

**If you are unsure of what you need to include, please look over the checklist in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/lets-help-id-request-users-help-themselves-with-a-floating-checklist-guide-for).**

### Please note that questions with **ONLY** **an image(s), audio, and/or video(s)** are **[off-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests/2726#2726)**.

Please *please* try to doing a [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source) yourself, instead of asking us to find it.

---

Taking cues from sites like TV & Movies.SE, Sci-Fi.SE, and Arqade, I've come up with the following guidelines:

> An [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) should have as many of the following points as possible:
>
> - Any description of the **leading/recurring character(s)** (i.e. physical description, behavior, etc.)
> - Any description of any **distinctive features**, including the plot and related elements (e.g. girls who are soda cans that do battle, or i.e., the setting, the plot)
> - What the **genre or cinematic style** was (e.g. mecha, sci-fi, fantasy, shonen, shoujo, seinen, noir, cyberpunk, etc.)
> - What the **drawing/animation style** is like
> - **When and where** you saw it (if you saw it when you were a kid, don't give your age, give the approximate year, and month if possible)
> - Who the **publisher, licensor, and/or distributor** was
> - **Type of media**: TV show, OVA, movie, manga, web-series, one-shot, etc.
> - Any **image(s), audio, or video(s)** related to the series (an exception may be made for questions with one or more of these items)
>
> **If you are unsure of what you need to include, please look over the checklist in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/lets-help-id-request-users-help-themselves-with-a-floating-checklist-guide-for).**
>
> For a detailed example and explanation of **how to properly ask for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions** w/o any audio-visual artefacts, please read [this answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/what-kind-of-policy-should-we-adopt-for-current-and-future-identification-reque/792#792).
>
> For a more in-depth explanation of the why we're asking you to provide such details, refer to [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2473/63).

In addition to the above guidelines, here are some suggestions to improve the quality of your [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions:

> ### Make Sure To Have A Descriptive Title
>
> All [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions **should have a title that is phrased or edited to be phrased as a question containing at least one pertinent detail** from the body of the question. Vague titles like "Requesting an anime identification" or "What is this anime show?" will lower the visibility of your question by fellow users since they'll have to click on it to find out what it's about. **This shows a lack of effort on your part.** Why should someone make an effort to help you if you can't properly format the question in your title?
>
> ### Don't Ask Too Much All At Once
>
> Please limit your [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions to ask for only **one series or piece per question**. Questions asking us to identify multiple unrelated media will only dilute the quality of responses with partial answers.
>
> ### Try Searching For The Image First
>
> Please questions with **ONLY** **an image(s), audio, and/or video(s)** are **[off-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests/2726#2726)**. If you're looking for the source of an anime image try doing a [**reverse image search**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-an-anime-using-reverse-image-search) search yourself.

We want to maintain a consistent quality for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question and have no choice but to enforce a minimum standard of acceptable quality.

We're not asking you to write an essay, but we expect you to at least make an attempt to fulfill the bare minimum, so we have some solid leads to go on:

> ### The Bare Minimum
>
> As a **bare minimum** your question needs meet ***three*** of these guidelines. **If you are unsure of what you need to include, please look over the checklist in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/lets-help-id-request-users-help-themselves-with-a-floating-checklist-guide-for).**
>
> Questions with **ONLY** **an image(s), audio, and/or video(s)** are **[off-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests/2726#2726)**. *Please* try to doing a [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source) yourself.
>
> Even if the aforementioned minimum guidelines are met, if the description provided is determined to be too ambiguous or generic, it will be put on hold as:
>
> - **"Off-Topic: This question does not meet our minimum standard for identification-based questions."**

Even if you question has been closed, it doesn't mean that it's the end of the line. Please try to review your question and make an attempt to addition details.

**If you are unsure of what you need to include, please look over the checklist in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/lets-help-id-request-users-help-themselves-with-a-floating-checklist-guide-for).**

If you need help, feel free to reach out to the moderators or other users. We'll try to help you as best we can.

> ### Reopening a Closed/On-Hold Question
>
> If your question has been ["put on hold" or "closed"](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2491/63), **it's not too late to edit your question** to include more details, **we'll be more than happy to reopen** your question once other users have reviewed and determined that there is **sufficient detail** to go about to helping you identify what you're looking for.

Comment: I think at least 3 would be significantly better than 2

Comment: Should we require specification of manga vs. anime?

Comment: @kuwaly i think that fits into 'type of media'

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I meant that it be required, instead of just one of the possible pieces of information to provide.

Comment: @kuwaly ah, yeah that does make sense

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to require 2 more of these in the case that the post has an image or video. In that case, the other points are typically mostly useless for the purpose of identification anyway, and in most cases wouldn't be known to the OP. Almost all questions we've had of this kind in the past haven't satisfied the, but as far as I know [only one](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7438/what-is-this-shoujo-manga-pic-included) is unanswered.

Comment: Should description of plot elements or events also be part of the list?

Comment: "Try Searching For The Image First" is a nonsense. If the OP was able to find the image of the serie he is asking about, and had small knowledge about the serie beforehand except for the name, finding an image for the sake of the question rules in this SE site would automagically answer his question.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli you underestimate the laziness and technical expertise of the average internet user. More than half of them don't even know they can search for a word in a browser using "Crtl+F." Site the SO and SU expect a minimum level of technical expertise when using their site, but we're a recreational site about Japanese cartoon and comic. Even though we're part of the SE family of site, expectations are set pretty low, since most of our traffic comes from the great wilderness that is internet search engine results.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Just like "homework" questions on certain SE sites and questions asking ppl to write code solutions without showing any work, we're telling users, if you just want us to do your work for you, sho that you've at least made an attempt yourself and why it didn't work. "I'm lazy, do this for me" is not an acceptable reason.

Answer (score 5):

As of 08/02/2016, **Image-only Identification requests** are off-topic.

If you wish to identify an image, please check out how to [Reverse Image Search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source).

Alternatively, if you have enough reputation you may ask in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-).

There are several other websites that may assist you in your search, but because of consistently low-quality issues, [we have elected](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/policy-review-image-only-id-requests) to not have these questions on our site

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1
>   If possible, do a [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-an-anime-using-reverse-image-search)
>
> Step 2
>   Copy template, fill in details, tag [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)
>
> Step 3
>   If you're already `-4` votes before you got here...
>   delete your question and ask again **using the template below**
>
> *Note: if you [can't delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/261498) it due not not being registered, leave a comment and if we see it, we'll delete it for you*

Identification Request Template (minimum of three):

- An Image
- When and where you saw it
- Media
- Genre
- Animation/Art style
- Distinctive Features and the story
- Character Descriptions
- Studio/Publisher/Distributor

---

**Example Identification Request**:

*What anime are these purple, red, and blue robots from?*

- **An Image**:  *any picture, youtube, sound clip, that's related*

[image]

- **When and where**: Bad- *I was 10*; Good- *2010*; Best- *Spring/Summer/Fall/Winter of X year*
  Fall 1995
- **Media**: *manga, show, movie, etc...*
  TV Show
- **Genre**: *shonen, shoujo, sci-fi, fantasy, slice of life, etc..*
  Shonen, Action, Mecha, Sci-fi
- **Animation/Art style**: *hand drawn, cg, sloppy, detailed, ghibli, etc..*
  Apocalyptic, Dark, Stylized
- **Distinctive Features**:  *plot, tropes, environment, themes*
  giant purple humanoid robot, plug suits, under ground city, angels wiping out mankind
- **Character Descriptions**:
  -Main character has repeated mental breakdowns, is a student, wears a white plug suit, constantly whining, etc..
  -Red head tsundere, red plug suit, red mech
  -Blue haired quiet girl, white plug suit, blue mech
- **Studio/Publisher/Distributor**:
  Gainax, Production I.G., Deen
  *other examples: Shaft/Bones/Sunrise/Kishimoto/Tite Kubo/Clamp...

  Kodansha/Square/ASCII Media Works/Jump...

  Funimation/Viz/CrunchyRoll...*

Comment: It's worth noting that [unregistered users cannot delete their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/261498).

Comment: @Maroon good point, how should we handle that then? should we delete it for them? I'm being completely serious.