# The Anime & Manga Quarterly Feedback Survey

Tags: discussion

Good evening/afternoon/morning, everyone!

As part of the improvement plan we're having as we get close to graduation, we'd like to have some feedback back from the community.

One of the decisions that we (your moderator team, Krazer, JNat, and myself) have made is to create a quarterly survey (the next one will be sent on September) to assess how things are going with the site community.

The form is powered by Google Forms, and is completely anonymous (unless of course, you'd like to tell us who you are).

We're hoping to gather as much feedback as possible, so **please be honest.** Even if your opinion differs from the the rest of the community does, **we'd still like to know**, that is the purpose of this survey.

Please be as descriptive as possible -- more detailed information will allow us to accurately assess site-wide issues and improve the community and the site as it nears graduation!

Thanks for helping out!

---

A note, again, since the survey is conducted **anonymously**, we can't really answer your question to be tailored for yourself, **because we don't know who's submitting it**. If you have personal questions, please ask them here on meta, but if you feel it's more of a private private, please feel free to ping [one of the moderators](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) in chat and they can discuss it with you privately.

Comment: This question is obsolete. No further input will be allowed through it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following are some of the queries we've received via the survey, and would like to address. If there are any more questions, feel free to contact any of the mods via **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/)**, and we'll arrange a private room to talk if you'd like. Also, meta posts about issues are always welcome. Of course, feel free to comment on this answer as well.

### I don't like there being so many identification requests

This one came up a few times. We currently have [**guidelines**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/63) regarding how identification requests need to be asked, any question that does not fit the bill, should be put on hold as **unclear what you're asking**. The rest of the questions are valid. Identification requests are a great way of discovering new anime for visitors, and we are not planning on putting them off-topic for the site.

### I want anime recommendations to be on-topic on the site

We understand, however, it's problematic, because it's exactly the opposite of how Stack Exchange sites work. Someone asks a question, people post answers, and the best answer is voted to the top. That last part is where the problem lies. When you allow for recommendations, **the most popular answer** will be voted to the top, and not **the best answer**. As always, you are free to drop in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/)** and we'll give you plenty of recommendations. We're already doing it!

### High reputation people hog all of the reputation

There's more than one way of getting reputation. Answering is one, asking questions is another, suggesting edits too. Don't be afraid to post what you think is a better answer even if someone already posted! **Remember, we encourage multiple answers per post!** An answer will be voted on if it's good, it has nothing to do with the reputation of the poster. (Don't forget that no one joins the site with high reputation, we all started from the same place).

### Requiring every answer to have a source doesn't make sense

I disagree. If you post an answer, it needs to be backed up by events that actually happened in the series. If it doesn't, then it is your opinion **which is also fine**, but even opinions need to be backed by solid evidence and events that happened, even if the question *itself* wasn't explicitly explained. If you make a wild speculation that has no base, you can expect us to want to know where it came from.

### Trivial questions should be allowed

All on-topic questions are allowed. Regardless of triviality. I never met someone with that problem on this site, feel free to contact us if you feel differently.

### Discourage people from voting down without a comment

I try to comment on every post I vote down, unless it's pretty obvious what's wrong with it (Lack of coherent language, one line that doesn't tell us much of the problem, expectations or demands for help, etc.) However, that cannot be enforced. Comments, as are downvotes, are a privilege, and not a requirement. We cannot force people to exert their privileges. This is not Anime & Manga policy but Stack Exchange policy.

### Discourage moderators putting questions on hold without a comment.

First of all, when a question is put on hold by a moderator without a comment, an automatic flag is raised, so those occasions are rare. Secondly, don't forget that the on hold reasons themselves are comments that need to be read. Example:

> #### unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Sometimes, you just don't need a comment.

Comment: "High reputation people hog all of the reputation" -- You can ask and answer your own questions as well, if you feel that it can help others.

Comment: _I don't like there being so many identification requests_ - the solution is to ask more questions about other things, so that there are proportionally fewer identification requests.

Comment: *Recommendations* - If they are tagged accordingly and the answers are based on given evidence, as every answer is supposed to be, wouldn't that offer more value than *recommendations from the chat*? Because new readers of the question would get a list of recommendations backed by the complete community and not only by those individuals who frequent the chat? This would especially be helpful for people who can't even visit the chat or maybe even dislike chats.