# Should there be a guide to answer identification request?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

we have a [guidelines for Identification Requests.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) So I thought it's better if we have same guidelines for answering those question, since there are many user who only answer it with so little information in it, so we can't tell if it's true or not unless OP clarify the answer.

Comment: I definitely agree we need some guidelines for this. The amount of 1 line name of anime is so high right now.

Comment: Yes, there absolutely should be. However, it's complicated by the fact that there are 2 very different types of ID requests: those with images/video and those with only memories. The guidelines for what constitutes a good answer for each type are very different, so we'd probably need 2 guides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proposal for guidelines

As stated in Logan M's comment there are 2 type's of identification there for here my proposal.

1) image of video identification.

- Name of character/series
- A short description of the character/series and why it is this character/series
- In case of a character image and potentially link to wiki or any anime site (e.g. MAL)
- In case of series link to wiki or any anime site (e.g. MAL)

2) Memory based identification

- Name of the series
- Why do you think so based on the description, what are the matching points.
- Short description of the series
- Link to wiki or any anime site (e.g. MAL)

With this there should be enough information for the OP to judge properly without having to go search around himself. And the answer itself should be off decent quality as well.

Comment: I think it should be link to any anime site, not just wiki since MAL and others are often use for searching anime/manga as well

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I think any site offering information is fine indeed. I just did wiki for ease of use, if you know a beter way to state it please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Yeah MAL or anidb is rather a better option as they usually include a cover image along with pictures, and lot more information.