# How should we answer “identification-request” question?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, guidelines

With so many 1 line name of anime answer right now. We've previously [voted that we need a set of guidelines](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/should-there-be-a-guide-to-answer-identification-request)

There's also a meta discussion about cleaned up [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) answer, but right now there's nothing that explain what constitutes a good answer to an identification request question and how to write one.

So what can I do to make a better answer for [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question

Comment: I think the answer in your linked question is okay, no?

Answer (score 5):

#### 1) Image or video identification

- Name of character/series
- Official image of the character/series (preferably not fanart image)
- A short description of the character/series, and why it is this character/series
- In case the question asks to identify a character, consider linking to wiki or [any anime database site (e.g. MAL or Anime-Planet)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4697/2869)
- In case the question asks to identify a series, consider linking to wiki or [any anime database site (e.g. MAL or Anime-Planet)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4697/2869)

#### 2) Text-based identification

- Name of the series
- Official image of the series (preferably not fanart image)
- Why do you think it is the series based on the description? What are the matching points?
- Short description of the series
- Link to wiki or [any anime site (e.g. MAL or Anime-Planet)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4697/2869)

With these, there should be enough information for the OP to judge properly without having to go search around himself. And the answer itself should be of decent quality as well.