# Fourth off-topic close reason implemented

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, close-reasons

As per **[Do we need a fourth off-topic reason for identification requests that contain too little detail?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/do-we-need-a-fourth-off-topic-reason-for-identification-requests-that-contain-to)**, a fourth off-topic close reason has been implemented.

It reads

> This identification request **contains too little detail to be answered**. Please refer to [these guidelines for writing good identification requests](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) and add more details to your question.

If you have insight/feedback/comments on this, feel free to post an answer to this question below.