# How long should we wait before voting to close?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

[identification-question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-question) has always been main attraction of pain and discussion. So to handle them properly [Fourth off-topic close reason](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/fourth-off-topic-close-reason-implemented) has been implemented. This is helping. But the time for closing is different.
Some questions get closed within an hour, whereas some remain for more than 24 hours waiting to be closed. In some questions, comments asking to add more detail are posted and in some they aren't. [This](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/what-is-this-anime-where-a-girl-has-her-heart-ripped-out) question is an example. The user traffic does play role how fast the question get closed.

So how long should we wait or it does not matter, [identification-question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-question) does not want to get involved in this messy part?

Comment: We can't enforce a maximum closing time, it sometimes takes a while until folks see the offending question.

Answer (score 4):

Closing a question is a completely temporary state. The close-edit-reopen cycle is a healthy cycle and I think we should encourage it more.

If you find a question that should be closed, vote to close it immediately. The close reason provides information (and you can add guidance in comments) as to how to improve the question and have it reopened.

If the question is edited, it will be added to the reopen review queue (and front page), where you'd be able to reopen it immediately and give answers.

If the question is good and the revised version should be reopened and you have an answer you want to give it, you can even flag it or ping one of us  mods in chat, and we'll be happy to reopen it for you.

### TL;DR

Close immediately. Reopen if needed.

Delete is a different story.