# Do we want identification requests for pornography?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

Yesterday, I closed a question (https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24236/). It was an identification request for pornography, though that may not have been directly apparent from the question alone.

This proved controversial; two users plus Krazer ended up reopening it. I suppose I must have misled myself into believing that porn-identification questions were unwanted here.

In order that we may have a documented position on this matter: do we want identification requests for pornography?

Comment: I felt that your actions may have been a bit too overly admonishing, but I do understand where you are coming from with this. We should find time to discuss this in more detail so we might don't do anything too rashly in the future.

Comment: There was also some discussion on this issue (specific to id requests) on [this answer to "Is explicit content off topic or not?"](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/2408/7579)

Comment: As the discussion on the link in my previous comment indicates, coming up with a policy on this issue is extremely complicated because the OP often doesn't know they're looking for porn and not something like To-Love-Ru which is graphic, but not *porno*graphic. In many cases you have to answer the question to find out that it's porn. I suppose we could, if we wanted, instantly delete any id request which turns out to be looking for porn.

Comment: @Torisuda "the OP often doesn't know they're looking for porn" - this is, of course, another one of the many degenerate things about ID requests. Is OP looking for porn? Is he looking for a James Bond movie? Is he looking for a comedy sketch he once saw? OP obviously doesn't know, so we either have to accept all identification requests that are sufficiently vague as to perhaps be an anime, or close questions based on their answers, neither of which is a good option.

Comment: @senshin I've already been convinced that the flaws of id requests outweigh their benefits.This issue, to me, is the [Barber Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox) that shows why id reqs and the SE model don't coexist well--if we want to limit certain kinds of content (e.g. hentai), but we allow id requests, then we can have perfectly valid questions which become invalid once they're answered and the answer turns out to be hentai. As you say, closing questions based on their answers is ridiculous...

Comment: ...but then how do we limit the content? We can't, because we don't know what the content is going to be. But limiting certain content is a fundamental part of SE. It's as if we couldn't tell whether a question was going to be primarily opinion based until we had ten answers that were all clearly unsubstantiated opinions. In my opinion, if we keep id reqs and refuse to embrace hentai, then this issue has only bad solutions.

Answer (score 11):

We really need to sit down and discuss how to categorize borderline  and explicit content. As I've said before, the topic of "hentai" and ecchi (see the *[To Love-Ru](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3455/To_LOVE-Ru)* manga) is unavoidable with anime and manga.

It is in my belief that we should allow them, but keep them in check with a few set rules. People that don't follow them will have their posts deleted without exceptions. All content deemed graphic will have the same treatment.

Answer (score 10):

Do we want them? Probably not.
Should banning/isnta-close be a policy? Also probably not.

I'm ambivalent towards questions related to porn, so long as nothing explicit is posted and the dialogue is civil, I don't see why it should be banned.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that the question was closed because the answer *might* have been hentai/porn.<sup>1</sup>

Looking at the borderline NSFW image, it doesn't suggest that it's hentai on the service, and since the OP hasn't posted something which is blatantly hentai or from a porn site, I am giving them the benefit of the doubt. The User already said they did a Google reverse image, and while I would rather have seen a screenshot as proof, I'm going to take their word for it (look at me being so trusting).

While the image can be arguably SFW/NSFW, it doesn't violate [Stack Exchanges Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) as I understand it. If it does then would this [Food Wars Foodgasm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4brN.png) violate it too? Or any image from an ecchi series? Or a screenshot from the *Strawberry Panic* anime of Hikari and Aname after they made love? My understanding is **no**, because they aren't Sexually Explicit Material, and personally I wouldn't be ashamed if someone saw me looking at the *Strawberry Panic* one even at work.

What if the answer wasn't a hentai manga, and someone just closed the question (in this case by moderator) saying that it's an "identify my porn" question in the comments, that could end up killing a question. It's one thing if it's a borderline NSFW image. However, what if a question is all text like [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14724/1587), and such a comment was made, but the answer turned out to be not a hentai because the poster of the comment mistook it for something else or what they believed was in fact incorrect.

So if we close questions because the answer *might* be hentai/porn, then what happens when the answers are Visual Novels like *Fate/Stay Night*, *Sono Hanabira*, *Kamidori Alchemy Meister*, *Kira Kira* or *Canvas 2*. Some may see these as hentai because of the adult content, despite having non-H versions of them (*Fate/Stay Night Realta Nua*), all ages anime adaptations (*Canvas 2*) or have their stories expanded in non-H material (*Sono Hanabira*).

If we were to created the message that a woman who undresses herself but covers herself as much as she can is hentai, then where does that leave *Neon Genesis Evangelion*? In the Director's Cut version, you can see the Rei Clones' nipples. Same thing with Misato after she had sex with Kaji, and her position in that scene is much more NSFW than a whole lot of lifeless Rei Clones. While the Rei Clones, with some research will get one an answer, it may not be like that with Misato

### So what should we do?

If we allow ID Requests for Hentai or H-Doujins then

- The question has to meet out [current guidelines](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892)
- Any and all images must not violate the [Stack Exchange Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy)

  - If they are borderline then they must be in a spoiler tag `>!` and a textual heading must be placed to indicate as such
- The wording of the question must be tasteful, avoiding porn language and using politically correct terms while also avoiding describing intercourse scenes
- Answers should not contain links to where one can read/buy it if the answer is hentai, but they should clearly indicate if they are hentai or just NSFW, since not all Madoka and Nanoha Shoujo Ai/Yuri Doujins are hentai, but still can be lewd or have suggestive themes (they still retain the lovey-dopey yuriness of the couples)

If we do decide to now allow them when we close them, in a comment we don't leave something like "take your porno elsewhere" but something like

> I have closing this question because the answer to this question can be found on Fakku (no need for a link) and it is clearly a hentai

This way, even if the OP didn't know it was hentai, they do now and other users can validate this claim when/if they want.

---

<sup>1: My mistake in reopening the question may have been misreading the times. Right now, when I look at the times for the answer and when the question was closed, the text still says "yesterday". However, the times have different dates</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what those users were thinking reopening that question. I think we've said it countless times that we don't want to become associated with "the site that identifies porn". *Even* if the work which this image comes from is not a hentai doujin (which I doubt isn't the case), **OP needs to find a less suggestive image** for the ID request to survive.

To those who are on the borderline about this: There is only one step from erotic to pornographic content, and at the rate we're receiving ID requests, it may be a very quick step.

Comment: Why even target ID-reqs specifically? If users can't use "suggestive images" then no one can post "suggestive images" anywhere. This is only one step away from banning questions on any lewd anime.

Comment: We're getting most of these from IDs and I think it's the most risky tag. Of course, all other tags may also be at risk, but not as much as IDs. In any case, I agree with Krazer.

Comment: @Frosteeze NaPaTa's work is R18+. No "lewd" anime is R18+ without being classified as outright hentai. Not even ridiculous shit like Shinmai Maou no Testament or To-Love Ru. There is a clear dividing line.