# Should we allow "From which episode is this image" questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, identification-questions

Recently I came across [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28447/which-episode-is-this-from-c%C2%B3) post, the author was asking from which episode a certain picture/screenshot was.

I wrongly voted to close this as a duplicate of ["Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source) (as we do with most image only identification requests).

The problem I have with this type of question is that it won't be of much use for anyone but the author.

Do we allow these kind of questions and if not what should we do with them?

Comment: [there](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14488/1458), [are](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20602/1458), [more](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15592/1458) of those type of questions around A&M then you think

Comment: Especially on the meta site, you should wait a little while until you accept an answer - people on the other side of the globe may have good input

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Ah didn't knew that. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: No problemo :-)

Comment: "there doesn't go much effort in writing them" is a rather bad reason to block questions. Indeed, many of the top questions on the site, both by views and by votes, can't have taken much effort to ask. I certainly put next-to no effort into asking http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2249, and got probably the best answer I've ever gotten on this site. Had I put in the effort, I could have answered it myself, but that isn't  (and shouldn't be) required...

Comment: And most of the top-viewed questions could have been answered by a Google search, but now we've answered them better and are on top of the Google searches. Put simply, effort is a great criterion for judging answers, but not a very useful one for judging whether a question ought to be on-topic.

Comment: @LoganM That's a very good point, updated the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I'm not a fan of these questions, I think they should be judged on a case-by-case basis.

as @LoganM has pointed out (and @Dimitrimx in his answer) there are instances of good questions that can be asked in this format.

Therefore, I think we should deal with low-quality questions as usual and indicate it with downvotes.

Comment: I agree with this. Dealing with them on a case-by-case basis is probably the best way to handle them.

Answer (score 4):

**Should we allow *“From which episode is this image?”* questions**: No, too broad

**Should we allow *"From which episode is ....?"* questions in general**: Debatable

*"From which episode is this image"* questions become too broad fairly easily. Unless a [reverse image search](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source) quickly manages to exclude the image from being from a specific movie, or visual novel.

If that is not the case, it would mean that the person answering would need to have a very in-depth knowledge of the source material, which sometimes includes more than thousands of hours of screen time. Or they have to go re-watch/read the whole thing just to get this one answer, which in most cases will not help a lot of people either way. This is based on some of the "from which episode" questions we already have on the site.

Then should we just disallow "from which episode" questions all together?

No, I don't think that is a good option. Most image identifications become too broad fairly fast. And even though this can also be the case for a bulk of the other "from which episode" questions out there, they could be borderline answerable. [Taking this K-on question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20602/in-which-episode-does-this-picture-from-the-opening-of-k-on-appear) and [this One Piece question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15592/in-which-episode-do-they-say-that-from-the-outside-the-straw-hats-dont-look-li), which are also fairly broad, yet are not bad questions in themselves.

In both cases, I think the questions should at the very least suffice to the 
[ID-request rules](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) in general, even if the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag may not always apply.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to ban all questions like this on the basis of a single below-average question? There's already quite a few better examples of questions like this, not to mention good reasons to ask them. And in the first place, "good or ban" is about the worst false dichotomy you can propose on meta. Even the one pointed to in the OP isn't remotely "too broad"; it's completely answerable, in fact in just a couple sentences. Moreover, these aren't ID requests at all; they're in-universe questions.

Comment: @loganm only below average, image related, in which episode questions. I dont think a lot of people would feel helped knowing that a specific screenshot occured in episode 530 16:12 at tbe 22nth frame. As opossed to asking when for example a specific quote was said